# contrasts in anova

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I understand the contrasts from previous posts and I think I am doing the right thing but it is not giving me what I would expect.

```
x <- c(11.80856, 11.89269, 11.42944, 12.03155, 10.40744,
       12.48229, 12.1188, 11.76914, 0, 0,
       13.65773, 13.83269, 13.2401, 14.54421, 13.40312)
type <- factor(c(rep("g",5),rep("i",5),rep("t",5)))
type
 [1] g g g g g i i i i i t t t t t
Levels: g i t
```

When I run this:

```
> summary.lm(aov(x ~ type))

Call:
aov(formula = x ~ type)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.2740 -0.4140  0.0971  0.6631  5.2082 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   11.514      1.729   6.659 2.33e-05 ***
typei         -4.240      2.445  -1.734    0.109    
typet          2.222      2.445   0.909    0.381    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 3.866 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3753,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.2712 
F-statistic: 3.605 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.05943
```

Here my reference is my type "g", so my `typei` is the difference between type "g" and type "i", and my `typet` is the difference between type "g" and type "t".

I wanted to see two more contrasts here, the difference between `typei+typeg`  and type "t" and difference between type "i" and type "t"

so the contrasts

```
> contrasts(type) <- cbind( c(-1,-1,2),c(0,-1,1))
> summary.lm(aov(x~type))

Call:
aov(formula = x ~ type)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.2740 -0.4140  0.0971  0.6631  5.2082 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.8412     0.9983  10.860 1.46e-07 ***
type1        -0.6728     1.4118  -0.477    0.642    
type2         4.2399     2.4453   1.734    0.109    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 3.866 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3753,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.2712 
F-statistic: 3.605 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.05943
```

When I try to do the second contrast by changing my reference I get different results. I am not understanding what is wrong with my contrast.

Comment: The right place for statistical questions is http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refence: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm

```
mat <- cbind(rep(1/3, 3), "g+i vs t"=c(-1/2, -1/2, 1),"i vs t"=c(0, -1, 1))
mymat <- solve(t(mat))
my.contrast <- mymat[,2:3]
contrasts(type) <- my.contrast
summary.lm(aov(x ~ type))

my.contrast
>      g+i vs t i vs t
[1,]  -1.3333      1
[2,]   0.6667     -1
[3,]   0.6667      0
> contrasts(type) <- my.contrast
> summary.lm(aov(x ~ type))

Call:
aov(formula = x ~ type)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-7.274 -0.414  0.097  0.663  5.208 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    10.841      0.998   10.86  1.5e-07 ***
typeg+i vs t    4.342      2.118    2.05    0.063 .  
typei vs t      6.462      2.445    2.64    0.021 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Residual standard error: 3.87 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.375,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.271 
F-statistic:  3.6 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.0594
```

Comment: Thanks @liuminzhao. The link is not longer available. I found that many people present this topic differently. Some with and some without the step of solving the matrix. Can you maybe recommend a good resource where this is explained since the link is not longer working.

Comment: @Jaynes01 I found another [link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html). Check section *DIY Contrasts*. Hope that helps. In short, it depends on whether the contrast are orthogonal or not. Doing the inverse is safer for the contrast function in R.